# Best practices of using theme colors: string, variable or reference from theme object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have [eslint-plugin-sonarjs](https://github.com/SonarSource/eslint-plugin-sonarjs) installed and it yells at me about me using the same string - color from palette - over and over again. It suggests me to write it to a variable and use the variable instead.

What would be the best practice:

1. Ignore eslint warning/disable it and use string names as usual

```js
// MyComponent.tsx
...
<Typography color={'primary.white'}/>
...
```

2. Write all theme colors in variables and use variables instead

```js
// colors.ts
export const WHITE_COLOR = 'primary.white'
// rest of the colors
...

// MyComponent.tsx
...
<Typography color={WHITE_COLOR} />
...
```

3. Use color from theme object

```js
// MyComponent.tsx
const theme = useTheme()
...
<Typography color={theme.palette.primary.white} />
...
```

4. Create hook `usePalette` that would return palette object from theme

```js
// usePalette.ts
const theme = useTheme();
return useMemo(() => theme.palette, [theme]);

// MyComponent.tsx
const palette = usePalette();
...
<Typography color={palette.primary.white} />
...
```

5. Or create a new `Typography` variant that uses the color

```js
// MuiTypography.ts variants
...
{
  props: {variant: 'white-text'},
  styles: (theme) => ({
    color: theme.palette.primary.white
  })
}
...

// MyComponent.tsx
...
<Typography variant={'white-text'} />
...
```

?

In my opinion options 2) and 3) are ridiculous. 2) creates unnecessary wrapping and 3) just doesn't feel right, too much to write.
1) is the sweetiest.

What do you think is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imho I would follow the recommendations of the library in such topics.
Thus, the documentation of MUI clearly states:

> The borderColor property can receive a string, which represents the path in theme.palette

Further, they provide following example:

```js
<Box sx={{ borderColor: 'primary.main' }} /> 
// equivalent to borderColor: theme => theme.palette.primary.main
```

Source: https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/

Following this argumentation, I prefer Solution 1) if appliable.

I wouldn't recommend solutions 3 and 4 if avoidable. However, if you like to apply one of these, I would use solution 3, since it avoids implementing another hook and useTheme already is provided by the framework.

Solution 5 depends on the use case. If it is a color which is applied to a single element - use `sx` props. If it is applied to a component (which occurs regularly, use styled components. If you use it in multiple cases or define a general color in your app, use a theme variable.